# Is it possible to get Android on a Nokia e65?

Tags: rom-flashing, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Does anybody know if it is possible to get android on a nokia e65?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

The [Symbian Series 60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29) operating system running on most of Nokia's high-end phones is very different from the Linux-based operating systems like Android, so someone would have to put a lot of work in to getting it working on devices designed for that. I haven't yet heard of any projects trying to convert any of Nokia's Symbian based phones. One of the primary problems is that Symbian generally runs on far lower powered devices and is a much smaller, simpler piece of software, so I'm not sure that Android could fit into a phone designed for that.

There is a [project](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/08/nokia-phones-android/) that aims to get Android working on Nokia's Internet Tablets (the N800 and N900 ranges) called [NITdroid](http://nitdroid.com/index.php?title=Main_Page). These devices are already running a customised version of Linux (in their case Nokia's Maemo, rather than our Android) so converting them to Android should be possible.